# how to display the last five hours time from current time(hh:mm ) 12 hour format in high charts?

Tags: javascript, date, time, highcharts

i am new to high charts and UI side development,
i need to display the chart with last five hours on x-axis from current time in 12 hour format.
please share your suggestion or jsfiddle here

Comment: please consider providing a code snippet of what are you working on

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gmetj2t9/

Comment: If answer below is not meeting your requirements, then please provide more info. If it does, then please mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
```

The result of n could be:

```
1460565067992
```

Then we substract 5 hours in milliseconds

```
var x= n-18000000
```

and we instantiate a new Date object based on this value

```
var lastFiveHours = new Date(x)
```

```js
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    console.log("Current date" + d);
    $("#currentDate").html(d);
    var x= n-18000000
    var lastFiveHours = new Date(x)
    console.log("Current date - five hours" + lastFiveHours);
    $("#currentDateFiveH").html(lastFiveHours);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="currentDate"></div>

<div id="currentDateFiveH"></div>
```

Comment: Which might be the same as `d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() - 5)`. With less code.